# AJAX and jQuery form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I need to make a Form but then a non reloading one, AJAX/jQuery. I tried to look at the other post but I'm not getting wiser. Help me out.

Its for a news reaction system.

This is the Reactions.php

```
<?php



$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM paginas '.

            'WHERE url="'.

            mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'";');



if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $pagina_id = $row['id'];

} else {

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO paginas SET url="'.

                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'";');

    $pagina_id = mysql_insert_id();

}

?><style type="text/css" media="screen">

    @import url('../_img/style.css');  

    </style>
    <script src="../../jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
      $j(function () {
        $j('form').bind('click', function (event) {

event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 

          $j.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $j('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('Je reactie is geplaatst !');
            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
<?php

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM reacties '.

                      'WHERE pagina="'.$pagina_id.'";');

if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {

    echo "<div class=\"box\">";

echo "<div class=\"menulitems\" style=\"margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;\">"; 

    echo 'Er zijn nog geen reacties.';

    echo "</div>";

        echo "</div>";



} else {



    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        // deze reactie weergeven

        echo "<div class=\"box\">";

        echo "<div class=\"titlesmall\">";

        echo ''.$row['naam'].' - '.$row['email'].'';

        echo "</div>";

echo "<div class=\"menulitems\" style=\"margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;\">"; 

        echo ''.$row['reactie'].'';

        echo "</div>";

        echo "</div>";

    }

}

?>



<div class="box">

<div class="titlesmall"><strong>Reageer</strong></div>

                <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">                

<form>

                <tr><td class="label">

                <label for="Naam">Naam*</label>

                </td><td colspan="1" align="left">

                <input class="required" type="text" name="naam" maxlength="255" />

                </td><td>       



                <tr><td class="label">

                <label for="Email">Email</label>

                </td><td colspan="1" align="left">

                <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" />

                </td><td>



                <tr><td class="label">

                <label for="Reactie">Reactie*</label>

                </td><td colspan="1" align="left">

                <textarea name="reactie" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>



                <br />



                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" />

                <input class="button" type="reset" name="submit2" value=" Reset " />



                </td><td>

</form>

</div>
```

This is the Post.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['naam'])) {

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO reacties SET pagina="'.

                $pagina_id.'", naam="'.$_POST['naam'].

                '", email="'.$_POST['email'].'", '.

                'reactie="'.$_POST['reactie'].'";');

}

?>
```

Comment: your code is horrible and vulnerable to sql injection, You are using deprecated api (musql_* function )

Comment: Do you have a better code for me ? 
You can find the site where the code is put at on: http://flashfm-radio.nl/
It's in dutch but you can find the news at 'Nieuws' or at the headlines at the middle on the top.
@NullPoiиteя